# 'Error 405 - Method not Allowed' when sending Ajax POST request in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am designing a simple Web API service that takes the inputs on an html form, turns those inputs into json, and then sends that to a Web API. I am working with ASP.NET Web API in Visual Studio 2017. Here is some of my code to help me explain better:

This is my controller method that I am calling:

```
[HttpPost]
public AssessModel PostAssessment ([FromBody] AssessModel assess)
{
    //Do something
    return assess;
}
```

This is the model (simplified) that I'm using:

```
public class AssessModel
{
    public Guid capitalassetassessmentid { get; set; }
    public string ownerid { get; set; }

    /*... Many more properties of int, bool, ect here ...*/

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string building { get; set; }
}
```

And finally this is the ajax call that I am using in my scripts:

```
$("form#my-form").submit(function (e) {
    //First line here takes all fields and puts them in an array
    var formArray = $(this).serializeArray();
    //Second line takes that array and puts it into json format.
    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(formArray);

    //Send request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/assessment/PostAssessment",
        data: jsonObj,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonObj) {
            $("#results").html(jsonObj.d);
        }
    });
});
```

So I am calling this ajax request when I submit a form. This ajax request should send my json as a string to the controller method but instead when I press submit I get an Error 405 - Method not Allowed. I am unsure why I am not allowed to send a POST verb to a controller method with the tag HttpPost.

It's also worth mentioning that my form tag is like this:

`<form id="my-form" class="form" method="POST">`

Any thoughts? Do I need to clarify anything? Let me know.

Comment: I would double check your routes. Are you sure the endpoint is api/assessment/postassessment? It might just be api/assessment.

Comment: I just double checked this and it did not fix the issue. Good thought though.

Comment: Try adding the code in the link to your web api web.config https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html .  Not sure if that's your issue, but I can give you a detailed answer if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var data = {};
var formArray = $('form#my-form').serializeArray();
for(var i in array)
{
    data[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;
}
var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: I changed my code but simply adding `[0]` where you indicated and it did not fix the issue. I suspect that the issue has something to do with this area though. Perhaps something with not providing json data that matches up well with the AssessModel class?

Comment: yes, if your json does not match the assessmodel class the default model binder will not be able to construct your object.

Comment: So my json needs to have <name, value> pairs that match up exactly with the properties of my AssessModel class or I will get this error? Because if that's the case then we have an open and shut case on the root cause.

Comment: your json needs to be { "ownerid": "someownerid", "name": "somename", "building": "somebuilding" }

Comment: Ah that would cause issues because currently my json is "wrapped" in an array because the original structure given by .serializeArray() causes the json to nest each object in an index. This is likely what is causing my issue as your original answer indicated. Thanks for the help.